# ExpressionEngine and Solspace Calendar and Relationship and Custom Event Selection and Grouping by Date

Tags: relationships, solspace-calendar

I made a channel with a relationship with calendar and events channel. The relationship with event is multiselect. I want to select the event manually from the backend(channel).
Now i am failed to show these event in front end with the grouping by date as shown in the image/attachment.

Please tell me; how can i do such functionalities.

http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/7yje2k0ht07jykhqyajm.png
(relationship pic)

http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/c3j2g4poltpz1tv7npi.png
(layout pic)

Comment: Can you please describe/paste what you have tried in your template to display this data?

Comment: http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/55oqgd59ljkkf0ce7vx.png

Comment: http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/55oqgd59ljkkf0ce7vx.png

Comment: http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/55oqgd59ljkkf0ce7vx.png                                 check it. i am failed to do grouping by dates.

Comment: When you say you "made a channel", did you create a custom field group and added Calendar fields to it, then associated the field group with the channel _you_ created? If so, this cannot work. **You must use the channels and custom field groups provided by, and installed automatically by, Calendar**. You cannot create your own channels and field groups for Calendar. However, you can add custom fields to the custom field groups created by Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, based on the comment about **making sure to use the channels and custom field groups provided by Calendar upon installation**, that the channels and field groups are set up properly.

Since `{exp:calendar:cal}` doesn't load the EE Channel:Entries library, it will likely not parse Channel module-based tags such as Relationship or Playa fields. In this case, you will need to pass the `event_id` from {exp:calendar:cal} into either `{exp:calendar:events}` (which loads the Channel:Entries library), or `{exp:channel:entries channel="calendar_events"}` if you're not using any date-based data. You may or may not need an embed to pass the ID.